# How to use a VPC default security group as a peer for another security group?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Using CDK (Typescript) I am trying to create a security group which can be accessed from my VPCs default security group.

I can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
    this.dbSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'db-security-group', {
      vpc: props.vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: false,
      securityGroupName: 'dbSecurityGroup',
    });

    this.dbSecurityGroup.connections.allowFrom(props.vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(5432));
```

I get an error saying:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IConnectable'`

This is because the `props.vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup` is a string and not an IConnectable type.

What is the correct way to access/use the vpcDefaultSecurity value to access another security group?

```
$ cdk --version
1.42.0 (build 3b64241)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it easy to convert a security group id (string) to a security group type using:

```
    const vpcDefaultSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, "SG", props.vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup);
    this.dbSecurityGroup.connections.allowFrom(vpcDefaultSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(5432));
```